# Red Hat Apache HTTPD error

Tags: apache, redhat, httpd.conf

Have setup a new test server and configure HTTPD conf file as per below:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
Listen 443

# URL:y1.y3t.com
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin gis@y3t.com
    ServerName y1.y3t.com
    ServerAlias y1.y3t.com
    ProxyTimeout 2700
    Timeout 2700

        SSLEngine on
#    SSLProtocol -SSLv2
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

    SSLCertificateFile /home/ssl/y3t.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ssl/y3t.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ssl/intermediate.crt

    ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.2/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.0.2/

    ErrorLog /appl/httpd/logs/y1.y3t.com-error_log
    CustomLog /appl/httpd/logs/y1.y3t.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

However, there seems to be some errors as per the httpd error_log.

Error Message:-

```
[root@sgdc-pvl-web03 ~]# tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Tue Dec 13 16:22:47 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 13 16:22:47 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 13 16:22:47 2016] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 256 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Tue Dec 13 16:22:47 2016] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Tue Dec 13 16:22:47 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 13 16:27:21 2016] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 13 16:27:22 2016] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Dec 13 16:27:22 2016] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Tue Dec 13 16:31:13 2016] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Dec 13 16:31:13 2016] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Tue Dec 13 16:32:14 2016] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Dec 13 16:32:14 2016] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
```

Can anyone advise on how can i resolve this? I'm still a newbie on this, really appreciate any help given!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are no errors there, those are clearly "notice" messages. Can't you see?

Answer (score 1):

this lines in error_log is only "notice" and are not error massages

like the informasion about "SSL FIPS mode" that is disable (in last line)

```
[Tue Dec 13 16:32:14 2016] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
```

does your web interface work correctly ?